# unhandled error event with create react app command

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm

I have been working with reactjs well and suddenly since yesterday I create a new application with create-react-app my-new-app and when I went to execute npm start pum that error attached capture https://ibb.co/qrN6YZ6 why can be that? I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. run `npm install` (maybe you remove some packege)
2. run `npm start`

Comment: I already tried that and nothing at all :( do you have any another idea?

Comment: remove `node_modules` folder in your project then `npm install` and `npm start` @JoseChavez